# Why is this image (image of the number 4) not classified correctly with this simple neural network in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

First year CS student here. I am preparing for a bigger project by trying to understand a simple MATLAB example with a convolutional neural network.

The MATLAB example (about Image Recognition) I mentioned can be found here:
https://nl.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/create-simple-deep-learning-network-for-classification.html

I have chosen two images to classify:

- **image3007.png**
- **image3007saveas.png**

**image3007.png** is an image I copied from the folder where the pictures of numbers are stored that were used to train/validate/test the network. So I would expect that it would be classified correctly (and it is).

**image3007saveas.png** was created by me, by simply opening image3007.png in software (I tried MS paint first, and then an online photoshop clone called photopea.com) and saving it with a different name. Again, I would expact it to be classified correctly (but it is not, you will see below).

**image3007.png** looks like this:
[image]

**image3007saveas.png** looks like this:
[image]

Of course both images look almost exactly the same (image3007saveas.png is slightly darker).

Both images have the size 28 x 28 x 1.

My script:

```
function cnn_letter_recognition

digitDatasetPath = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','nnet','nndemos', ...
    'nndatasets','DigitDataset');
imds = imageDatastore(digitDatasetPath, ...
    'IncludeSubfolders',true,'LabelSource','foldernames');
%------------
fracTrainFiles = 0.6;
fracValFiles = 0.2;
fracTestFiles = 0.2;
[imdsTrain, imdsValidation, imdsTest ] = splitEachLabel(imds, ...
    fracTrainFiles, fracValFiles, fracTestFiles, 'randomize');
%------------
layers = [

    imageInputLayer([28 28 1])

    convolution2dLayer(3,10,'Padding','same')
    batchNormalizationLayer 
    reluLayer 

    maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)

    convolution2dLayer(3,10,'Padding','same')
    batchNormalizationLayer
    reluLayer
    
    fullyConnectedLayer(10)
    softmaxLayer 
    classificationLayer];
%------------
options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'InitialLearnRate',0.01, ...
    'MaxEpochs',10, ...
    'Shuffle','every-epoch', ...
    'ValidationData',imdsValidation, ...
    'ValidationFrequency',30, ...
    'ValidationPatience', 5, ...
    'Verbose',false, ...
    'Plots','training-progress');
%------------
net = trainNetwork(imdsTrain,layers,options);
%------------
YPred = classify(net,imdsTest);
YTest = imdsTest.Labels;

accuracy = sum(YPred == YTest)/numel(YTest)
%------------
im1 = imread('image3007.png');
YPred_Should_Be_4 = predict(net,im1)

im2 = imread('image3007saveas.png');
YPred_Should_Be_4_too = predict(net,im2)
```

The result I get is this:

```
accuracy =

    0.9900


YPred_Should_Be_4 =

  1×10 single row vector

    0.0000    0.0001    0.0000    0.0000    0.9987    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0012


YPred_Should_Be_4_too =

  1×10 single row vector

    0.0006    0.9474    0.0182    0.0044    0.0022    0.0041    0.0168    0.0011    0.0008    0.0043
```

Which means:

- **image3007.png** is classified correctly as the number 4.
- **image3007saveas.png** is classified as the number 1, although the image itself is almost identical to the other image.

im1 (**image3007.png**) in the workspace:

[image]

im2 (**image3007saveas.png**) in the workspace:

[image]

I tried increasing the brightness of image3007saveas.png to make it more similar to the original image.
I tried to set epoch to 100 at the options in the code to make the training last longer.
The outcome did not change.